# Perturbing the approximation property from the Lipschitz-free space to stay in the Wasserstein space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, operator-theory, metric-spaces, lipschitz-spaces

Let $(X,d,x)$ be a separable pointed metric space and let $\mathcal{F}(X)$ be its **Arens-Eells** *(also called its Lipschitz-Free space; in the case where $X$ is Banach)* space.  We view the $1$-Wasserstein space $\mathcal{W}(X)$ as a convex subset of $\mathcal{F}(X)$ via the usual embedding:
$$
\mathcal{W}(X)\ni \mu \mapsto \left[f\mapsto \int_{u\in X} f(u) [\mu-\delta_{x}](du)\right] \in \operatorname{Lip}_0(X)' =:\mathcal{F}(X); \qquad \boldsymbol{(1)}
$$
where the functions $f$ on the right-hand side belong to $\operatorname{Lip}_0(X)$ (so $f(x)=0$, but for generality I have defined them on all of $\operatorname{Lip}(X)$).

**THE ASSUMPTION:**

We assume that $(X,d,x)$ is such that $\mathcal{F}(X)$ has the **bounded approximation property (BAP)** (extensive research has been conducted over the last decade on this question, and many "interesting/typical" pointed metric spaces satisfy this assumption).  Furthermore, in a broad range of "tame cases" explicit estimates on the operator-norm of the sequence of operators realizing the bounded-approximation property are known (for instance for any closed-subset of an $N$-dimensional Euclidean space the rate is $C\sqrt{N}$ for some universal constant $C$.

---

**THE QUESTION(s):**
Let $K\subseteq \mathcal{W}(X)$ be given and let $(T_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of finite-rank operators converging to the identity on $K$ and whose operator norm is uniformly bounded by some constant $\lambda>0$.

Then, can we perturb the build a sequence of affine maps $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ which are finite-rank, approximate the identity, and such that $A_n(K)\subseteq K$ for all $n$?

*Comment:* I expect that is possible and that one can construct this map by exploiting the fact that $\mathcal{W}(X)$ is a convex subset of a co-dimension $0$ affine subset of $\mathcal{F}(X)$.

Comment: As far as I know, exact projections onto nearest points of convex subsets requires reflexivity, which you never have for $\mathcal{F}(X)$ when $X$ is infinite. What you're asking for is weaker, but still seems unlikely to me.

Comment: BTW if $X$ isn't compact then you don't get $\mathcal{W}(X) \subset \mathcal{F}(X)$, but you can slightly modify the definition of $\mathcal{W}(X)$ so that this works.  This is probably well-known, but anyway it's done in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.11205).

Comment: @NikWeaver Ins't the modification just $\mu \mapsto \mu - \delta_{x}$ (for the distinguishe point $x$)?

Comment: @NikWeaver Fair, initially I was thinking of $\epsilon$-best projections (like in Respov's book; Chapter 6) but this also seemed difficult and a likely less explored research question by others.

Comment: As a final thought, on my end, if we equip $\mathcal{F}(X)$ with a Borel probability measure $\nu$, then since $K$ is compact then one can combine the measurable maximum theorem (18.19 in Charalambos et al.'s book) and Lusin's Theorem to conclude that a metric projection must exist on a closed subset of $\mathcal{F}(X)$ of arbitrarily-high $\nu$-probability.  (Though, this is kind of cheating).

Comment: No, the problem is that if $X$ is unbounded then you can have probability measures whose integral against some Lipschitz function is infinite.

Comment: @NikWeaver Ah, you're right; this is very simple actually.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Sorry I can't be more helpful about your main question ...

Comment: @NikWeaver No worries; but it's also a pleasure to discuss with you (especially after reading you book/some of your papers)